# Adding style to easyUI DateBox React component

Tags: reactjs, jquery-easyui

I would simply like to add some styling to the DateBox react component defined as in the code below

Let's say I'd like to change the width of the panel: something like

```
<DateBox style="width=300"></DateBox>
```

or

```
    <DateBox>
      width=300 
    </DateBox>
```

but these attempts did not work.

My actual component is:

```js
import React from "react";
import { DateBox } from 'rc-easyui';

 
class DatePick extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DateBox>
        </DateBox>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default DatePick;
```

How can I change the DateBox component styling (not the div in which it is contained)?

Thank you for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use style attribute like this

```
<DateBox style={{width:'300px'}}>
</DateBox>
```